# pylab/networkx; no node labels displayed after update

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

After I have updated matplotlib to the current version I encounter a problem with node labels in networkX: if I use the `nx.draw(G)` command, I get a graph, but no labels are displayed. But let's speak with examples:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

T=nx.Graph()
T.add_edge(0,1)
nx.draw(T)
plt.show()
```

this returns a valid plot, but with no node labels. Even if I pass the labels directly like in

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

T=nx.Graph()
T.add_edge(0,1)
labs={}
labs[0]='cake'
labs[1]='cookie'
nx.draw(T,labels=labs)
plt.show()
```

there are still no labels. I'm pretty sure it (especially the upper one) was working yesterday before the update. So was there a change from matplotlib 1.3.x (don't remember the exact one I was running previously)? The current versions are:

```
matplotlib (1.4.0)   (had to downgrade the pyparsing to 1.5.7 after updating the matplotlib)
networkx (1.9)
python 2.7.6
Mac OS X 10.9.4
```

Little Extra: if i run the upper code with `nx.draw(T, with_labels=True)` I get a plot (extra window on my settings) and when I close it a `TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation` pops up. It does not happen if I run `nx.draw(T, with_labels=False)`, which is very confusing, since I thought `with_labels` argument takes a boolean ([see here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw)), which it (partially) does not....?

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Edit: @tcaswell hope that helps!

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     57     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     58         before(artist, renderer)
---> 59         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60         after(artist, renderer)
     61 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
   1077         dsu.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
   1078         for zorder, a, func, args in dsu:
-> 1079             func(*args)
   1080 
   1081         renderer.close_group('figure')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     57     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     58         before(artist, renderer)
---> 59         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60         after(artist, renderer)
     61 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.pyc in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2090 
   2091         for zorder, a in dsu:
-> 2092             a.draw(renderer)
   2093 
   2094         renderer.close_group('axes')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     57     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     58         before(artist, renderer)
---> 59         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60         after(artist, renderer)
     61 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
    536         renderer.open_group('text', self.get_gid())
    537 
--> 538         bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(renderer)
    539         trans = self.get_transform()
    540 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    309         tmp, lp_h, lp_bl = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent('lp',
    310                                                          self._fontproperties,
--> 311                                                          ismath=False)
    312         offsety = (lp_h - lp_bl) * self._linespacing
    313 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.pyc in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
    164         size = self.points_to_pixels(points)
    165         width, height, descent = self.gc.get_text_width_height_descent(
--> 166             six.text_type(s), family, size, weight, style)
    167         return  width, height, 0.0*descent
    168 

TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

(I'm neither a mathematician nor a programmer, but willing to learn, so please be patient!)

Comment: Shouldn't `import networks` be `import networkx`?

Comment: damn autocorrect function on Mac :( it is the right way in the code, was just corrected in the browser

Comment: I can confirm that the label's don't show up with 1.4.

Comment: Can you give the full-stack traces from the `TypeError`?

Comment: I've added the full traceback message to the question.

Comment: So with `matplotlib==1.4.0` and `networkx==1.8.1`, I was getting those errors not matter if labels were on or off. After updating to `networkx==1.9`, I only get the same errors when labels are on (or used) in general.

Comment: Those errors make not a whole lot of sense....

Comment: Are you using the osx backend?  See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3470 associated links.  Try using any of the *agg backends.

Comment: Changing the backend to *Agg (TkAgg in my case) helped, now I get the labels when using 'with_labels=True' and no error message. I think it would be good if you add this to you answer below, so I can accept it since it resolves the entire problem. (Giving me a whole lot of questions in general about all this why and how, but thats a whole different story). Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @olga.bio Can you leave a note on that gh issue with any configurations you have in your rcparam?  Something in broken in the osx backend.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is hitting a known (but unresolved) bug in the OSX backend ([#3470](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3470)).

Switching to one of the Agg based backends should 'resolve' the problem by avoiding it.

UPDATE

Part of the problem has been identified and merged https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3564.  This fix should be in mpl v1.4.1 and higher.