# How to "switch to one of the Agg backends"?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, networkx

I have the same problem as [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865975/pylab-networkx-no-node-labels-displayed-after-update/25870916), namely that when using matplotlib and networkx on Mac OS X 10.8.5, labels are not displayed.

The solution in that thread is "Switching to one of the Agg based backends should 'resolve' the problem by avoiding it" by @tcaswell [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25902824/2487607). Can someone tell me what that means/ how to do it?

I'm sorry to start a new thread, but I don't have enough reputation to comment or ask any questions on the previous post! If someone could merge this post and the previous, that would be best.

Thanks
Bobby

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work (note that `use` needs to be called before pyplot is imported):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

There are more details in other questions if you search for "Agg" or "backend", e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930524/how-to-set-backend-in-matplotlib-in-python).

Edit: Sorry, maybe I didn't understand exactly what you are trying to do. As sebix points out,  `Agg` is a backend for plotting to a file (i.e. non-interactive plots), and if you want an interactive plot to appear on the screen, then use one of the [interactive backends](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend). e.g. `Qt4Agg` (note this needs PyQt4).

Comment: Thank you. I can now `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` without any errors! But it doesn't show the plots :( For example: 
`import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(10)
y = [a**2 for a in x]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()`

finishes with no errors and no plots. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to make a code block when commenting.

Comment: I should mention that switching `plt.show()` for `plt.savefig(...)` works! So if I keep the Agg backend, I can't display plots (they're supposed to be interactive), and if I don't use 'Agg' I get the error from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865975/pylab-networkx-no-node-labels-displayed-after-update/25870916)

Comment: The 'Agg'-backend is supposed to show nothing - it works headless. If you want and interactive interface, look at `TkAgg`, `GtkAgg` or `QtAgg`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
plt.switch_backend('Qt4Agg')
```