# Text missing from graph using networkx and matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I have installed networkx and matplotlib using pip on Mac Os 10.10.3 for python 3.3.

When I run the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def simple_graph():

    #create an empty graph
    G = nx.Graph()

    #add three edges
    G.add_edge('A','B');
    G.add_edge('B','C');
    G.add_edge('C','A');

    #draw the graph
    nx.draw(G)

    #show
    plt.show()

simple_graph()
```

I get the graph as expected but all the text is missing. Any suggestions why?

Comment: Are you wanting node labels? you may prefer calling `nx.draw_networkx(G)`

Answer (score 1):

Pass param `with_labels=True`:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def simple_graph():

    #create an empty graph
    G = nx.Graph()

    #add three edges
    G.add_edge('A','B');
    G.add_edge('B','C');
    G.add_edge('C','A');

    #draw the graph
    nx.draw(G,with_labels=True)

    #show
    plt.show()

simple_graph()
```

Yields the plot:

[image]

If instead you call [`draw_networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx):

[image]

Essentially `nx.draw` calls `nx.draw_networkx` but without certain params set.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is as EdChum answered.

However, it looks like you may be using using ipython.  In that case, even including `with_labels=True` can fail.  If you plot it and save it it will have the label, but it won't display the label with the `plt.show()` command.  This is a bug which (according to comments) has been fixed in an upcoming release.

If I edit your code to have `with_labels=True`:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def simple_graph():

    #create an empty graph
    G = nx.Graph()

    #add three edges
    G.add_edge('A','B');
    G.add_edge('B','C');
    G.add_edge('C','A');

    #draw the graph
    nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)

    #show
    plt.show()

simple_graph()
```

and run it in ipython I get the plot, but without labels appearing, and the error message:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", >line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1079, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2092, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 538, in draw
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(renderer)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 311, in _get_layout
    ismath=False)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 166, in get_text_width_height_descent
    six.text_type(s), family, size, weight, style)
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

This is a known bug.  Some details can be found here: [pylab/networkx; no node labels displayed after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865975/pylab-networkx-no-node-labels-displayed-after-update)

Comment: This is fixed on current master and will be released with 1.5

Comment: @tcaswell Thanks - please follow up when that is released.

Comment: I'll leave that to you.  Keep your eye out for a release annoucement.